# How to install php7_module in SUSE Linux Enterprise Server

Tags: apache-http-server, suse

I have Apache installed on SLES 12 SP4. When I list the modules: `sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -M`, I notice that `php7_module` is not there. How do I add this? I've tried various permutations on `sudo zypper install php7_module` / `libapache-mod-php`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package that you want is: `apache2-mod_php7`

```
zypper install apache2-mod_php7
```